# Android Fragments getView returning the parent of the view?

Tags: android, fragment

So I have encountered some odd behaviour when it comes to the getVIew() method in the fragment class. From the documentation I am expecting to get the view created in the onCreateView method as is stated here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView()

"Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)), if provided"

Now, I have a view that has in it a fair number of children so I wanted to try and save when i try and "findViewById" by implementing a ViewHolder class similar to the common way it is done in ListView Adapters which I set to be the tag of the view returned from the onCreateView.

The odd behaviour occurs later when I call the getView method. It appears that the fragment is returning the parent of the view I create rather than the view I create which results in a null tag being returned.

I wrote a small price of code to print out a view (nesting the children if the view is actually a viewGroup) and this is what I get.

```
 android.widget.ScrollView  android.widget.ScrollView@4242dec0
 /android.widget.ScrollView
```

and when I print it later using the getView() method I get

```
 android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout
     android.widget.ScrollView  android.widget.ScrollView@4242dec0
     /android.widget.ScrollView 
 /android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout
```

As you can see the ScrollView is the view I actually create in the onCreateView method. So why is getView returning the parent instead of the view?

Comment: The `NoSaveStateFrameLayout` appears only in the fragments from the compatibility package if I'm not mistaken. Anyway you could always use `getView().findViewById(R.id.theIdOfTheScrollView)`.

Answer (score 1):

The support library inserts an additional view into the view hierarchy. According to a comment in NoSaveStateFrameLayout.java: "Pre-Honeycomb versions of the platform don't have View.setSaveFromParentEnabled(), so instead we insert this between the view and its parent."

So you will need to either check for this with something like:

```
View myView = (NoSaveStateFrameLayout)getView();
if (myView != null) {
  myView = myView.getChildAt(0);
}
```

Or keep track of the view returned by onCreateView in an instance variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was boggled why getView() is not returning the same view I returned in onCreateView()

Comment: I'm not being able to use NoSaveStateFrameLayout in my code though, even though I'm using the v4 compat library.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are creating the Adapter before `onCreateView` completes? I had an issue where I had a function calling getView() and manipulating the the layout elements before onCreateView returned, causing the incorrect view to be used. I ended up sending the inflated view from onCreateView to the function, and it worked worked out fine.